# Checking if an ORG Wide Email Address has been verified in Apex

Tags: email, singleemailmessage, org-wide-email

I'm running into an issue where emails are not sending when an Org Wide Email Address is not verified. No exception is thrown either.

[image]

In apex, I'm resolving the ORG wide that matches the users email:

`Id emailId = [SELECT Id FROM OrgWideEmailAddress WHERE Address = :userEmail].Id;`

I'd like to somehow check if their email is verify and fall back to a "default" email when it is not.

I'd expect this to just be a field on the [OrgWideEmailAddress object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_orgwideemailaddress.htm) I could filter on, but unfortunately there is not.

Is there any way to check this via apex?

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67153/to-check-if-org-wide-email-is-verified-in-apex

Comment: ... apparently I've already been here before. Flagging as duplicate

Comment: It's weird that I'm not seeing the `UNVERIFIED_SENDER_ADDRESS` exception being thrown

Comment: ah... I had allOrNothing = false when sending :(